# How to abort an ongoing GWT RequestBuilder request?

Tags: java, gwt

I have some queries made by GWT (2.4) `RequestBuilder` that might take a long time to execute. In these cases I'd like to allow the user cancelling the request. As it is only a query aborting the processing on the server side would not have any harmful side-effect. Even the wasted server side CPU cycles do not matter if the solution involves any. Here is an example of the situation:

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(
    RequestBuilder.GET, FOOBAR_SERVICE_URL);

 requestBuilder.sendRequest("",
   new RequestCallback<ResultList>() { .... });

// I'd like to cancel the request when a Cancel button is pressed
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancelling a server-side GWT call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276970/cancelling-a-server-side-gwt-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sendRequest()` method of `RequestBuilder` returns instance `Request` class, which has `cancel()` method,which allows you to cancel request.

E.g.

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(
    RequestBuilder.GET, FOOBAR_SERVICE_URL);

Request request = requestBuilder.sendRequest("",
   new RequestCallback<ResultList>() { .... });

...

//user clicked cancel button
request.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used RequestBuilder, so I can't be sure there is not a better mechanism or something doing the feature you describe already.

One way to do it is to keep a reference to your callback and if the user presses "Cancel" set a flag on the callback to say that it has been cancelled (`setCancelled(true)`). When receiving the response, check that flag and if it is true, just throw away the response.

I don't think that you can actually "kill" the requests.