# Why am I getting a SocketException in a long running application?

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a Java socket server application which is giving me error if i run it for long time say 4-8hrs, below is the list of error i get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:130)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
        at LiveRate.processData(LiveRate.java:224)
        at LiveRate.mainLiveRate(LiveRate.java:265)
        at LiveRate.liveRate(LiveRate.java:126)
        at LiveRate.run(LiveRate.java:119)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

My socket application reads some values from another TCP/IP server and stores the value temporarily and offers the same to other client.Not sure If these error are because of Heavyload on the system or because of the Memory issues.Please help

Comment: This question may give you some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Answer (score 4):

It is probably neither (directly) load or memory related.  Instead, it is more likely to be one of the following:

- the remote service is shut down / falls over and is restarted on a regular basis,
- the remote service has decided to close its end of the connection because it is "idle",
- network connectivity is intermittent and you are occasionally encountering an outage or congestion-induced "brownout" that is too long,
- you are using NAT or similar, and the port number that was being used for the connection has been reclaimed by the NAT gateway, or
- something is enforcing some policy about TCP/IP connections being open for too long.

---

The bottom line is that your client software needs to be able to cope with lost connections if you want ti to run for extended periods of time.  This is the way that the internet works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's because your connection gets reseted by your Internet Provider every 24 hours.

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark considering the OP says they only need to run it for 4 to 8 hours...

Comment: When the connection gets reset within this 4 to 8 hours, that's where the problem lays.

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark considering you don't know who the ISP is or what their policies are.