# TCP server connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

i have a server that is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class MyTcpServer {

    static ServerSocket server = null;
    static Socket connectionSocket = null;
    static BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
    static PrintWriter outToClient = null;

    public static void initiateService() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(1234);

            System.out.println("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 1234");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("There is some error!! Please try some other port!");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void awaitRequest() throws IOException {
        String instructionsToClient = null;
        System.out.println("Service Ready");
        while (true) {
            connectionSocket = server.accept();

            inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            outToClient = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(),
                    true);

            String messageToClient;
            String messageFromClient = null;

            synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {

                System.out.println("Client:"
                        + connectionSocket.getInetAddress()
                        + " connected on port :"
                        + connectionSocket.getLocalPort());

                messageToClient = "Welcome!!!! You are now connected to our server!! We ensure a reliable service.\n"
                        + "\n Your IP:"
                        + connectionSocket.getInetAddress()
                        + "  \n"
                        + connectionSocket.getLocalPort()
                        + "::::MESSAGE FROM SERVER::::\n"
                        + "Lets play Water jug puzzel!! You give me sizes of two water Jars\n"
                        + "And a desired level to be achieved! Ill tell you whether the problem\n"
                        + "is solvable or not!!\n"
                        + "Comprande~?\n"
                        + "Enter your choice Y/N \n"
                        + "--------------------------";

                synchronized (outToClient) {

                    outToClient.println(messageToClient);
                    outToClient.flush();

                    System.out.println("invite sent to the client!!");

                }

                synchronized (inFromClient) {

                    messageFromClient = inFromClient.readLine();
                    System.out.println("The user says: " + messageFromClient);

                }

                if (messageFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    messageToClient = "Wow!! awesome! Throw a challenge at me!"
                            + "\nEnter Large jug volume,Small jug volume,Desired level in comma separated fashion"
                            + "\nFor example (5,3,2)"
                            + "\n--------------------------";

                } else if (messageFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    messageToClient = "Great! we dont have a problem with you not playing the puzzel!"
                            + "Do you wanna exit? press q and smack Enter key!"
                            + "\n--------------------------";
                } else {
                    messageToClient = "psssst!!! Wanna quit??"
                            + "press q and smack Enter key!"
                            + "\n--------------------------";
                }

                synchronized (messageToClient) {

                    outToClient.println(messageToClient);
                    outToClient.flush();

                    System.out.println("reply sent to the client!!");

                }
                messageFromClient = "";
                synchronized (inFromClient) {
                    System.out.println("Entered");

                    messageFromClient = inFromClient.readLine();
                    System.out.println("The user says: " + messageFromClient);



                if (messageFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    System.out.println("ui");
                    messageToClient = "Thank you!!"
                            + "\n--------------------------";
                } else {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(messageFromClient,
                            ",");

                    if (st.countTokens() != 3) {
                        messageToClient = "See! the input you gave has some problem!"
                                + "\n you havent followed the instructions properly"
                                + "\n Thank you!! Bye for now! come back later!"
                                + "\n--------------------------";
                    } else {
                        messageToClient = "Thanks! i am solving it!"
                                + "\n--------------------------";


                    }
                }
                }

                synchronized (messageToClient) {

                    outToClient.println(messageToClient);
                    outToClient.flush();

                    System.out.println("problem answered sent to the client!!");

                }

            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        initiateService();
        awaitRequest();
    }

}
```

and i have a client accessing this particular server!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyTcpClient {

    static Socket clientSocket;
    static BufferedReader inFromUser;
    static PrintWriter outToServer;
    static BufferedReader inFromServer;

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        String FromServer;
        String ToServer;

        clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);

        // for user to type messages in client mode
        inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // client program uses this to write on the server
        outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // servers talk back to the client
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        FromServer = "";
        while (!FromServer.equals("--------------------------")) {
            FromServer = readFromServer();
            System.out.println(FromServer);

        }


        System.out.println("Enter choice!");
        String choice = "";

        choice = inFromUser.readLine();
        System.out.println("" + choice);

        synchronized (outToServer) {

            outToServer.println(choice);
            outToServer.flush();
        }

        FromServer = "";
        while (!FromServer.equals("--------------------------")) {
            FromServer = readFromServer();
            System.out.println(FromServer);

        }

        choice = inFromUser.readLine();
        System.out.println("" + choice);

        synchronized (outToServer) {

            outToServer.println(choice);
            outToServer.flush();
        }

        FromServer = "";
        while (!FromServer.equals("--------------------------")) {
            FromServer = readFromServer();
            System.out.println(FromServer);
        }

    }

    static String readFromServer() throws IOException {
        String response = inFromServer.readLine();
        return response;
    }

}
```

on a successful run the output at the server side is something like this:

```
TCPServer Waiting for client on port 1234
Service Ready
Client:/127.0.0.1 connected on port :1234
invite sent to the client!!
The user says: y
reply sent to the client!!
Entered
The user says: 5,3,2
```

and the output at client side is something like this:

```
Welcome!!!! You are now connected to our server!! We ensure a reliable service.

 Your IP:/127.0.0.1  
1234::::MESSAGE FROM SERVER::::
Lets play Water jug puzzel!! You give me sizes of two water Jars
And a desired level to be achieved! Ill tell you whether the problem
is solvable or not!!
Comprande~?
Enter your choice Y/N 
--------------------------
Enter choice!
y
y
Wow!! awesome! Throw a challenge at me!
Enter Large jug volume,Small jug volume,Desired level in comma separated fashion
For example (5,3,2)
--------------------------
5,3,2
5,3,2
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at MyTcpClient.readFromServer(MyTcpClient.java:85)
    at MyTcpClient.main(MyTcpClient.java:78)
```

The exception that is being raised here is only when a string separated with commas is supplied. Dont have an idea what is going wrong , can anybody share something?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, no exceptions

Comment: Same here, works fine on my end

Comment: when i am entering 5,3,2 or something like that still the error persists :(

Comment: 'Connection reset' != 'connection refused'. Don't be sloppy about error messages, or anything else in computing for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some *other* problems in your code:

```
static ServerSocket server = null;
```

Should not be static.

```
static Socket connectionSocket = null;
```

Should be neither static nor even an instance member. It should be a local variable in the method that calls accept().

```
static BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
static PrintWriter outToClient = null;
```

Ditto in this case, but in the general case they should be instance members of a per-connection class that you instantiate for every newly accepted socket. This is usually a `Runnable,` whose `run()` method does all the I/O for that client, or calls methods that do so.

Comment: i tried making all the changes as you said here but still the same!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't going to try your code but as two people already did that I think that *maybe* the problem isn't your code.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/585643/1564493).