# Communications link failure while connecting to mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql database from my android application.

I'm getting **Communications link failure** error.
Below is the code snippet:

```
public class MySqlConnector {
    private Connection con = null;
    private String s = "";
    private String username = "root";
    private String password = "password01";
    private String connectionString;

    public String ConnectToDb() {
         connectionString ="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.104:3306/mydatabase";
        //connectionString="jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.0:3306/mydatabase";
        // connectionString="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase";
        //connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://MainSrv04:3306/mydatabase";
        // connectionString="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";

        // connectionString =
        // "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?user=root&password=password01&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username,
                    password);

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT First_Name FROM mydatabase.custinfo where CardNumber=5325784707";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            s = rs.getString("First_Name");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                    Log.i("MySqlConnector", "Database connection terminated");
                } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */
                }
            }
        }

        if (s == "") {
            s = "No Result";
        }
        Log.i("MySqlConnector : s=", s);

        return s;
    }
}
```

---

I tried all possible combinations as showed in comments and getting following error in *caused by* field in logcat:

- while using localhost --> `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:3306 - Connection refused`
- while using 127.0.0.1 --> `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:3306 - Connection refused`
- while using 10.0.0.0 --> `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out`
- while using 192.168.1.104 --> `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out`
- while using MainSrv04 --> `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: MainSrv04`

---

I also pinged `mysql` port through **telnet** and it's working.
Also, I have taken care of privileges.

But still I'm getting `Communications link failure` error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So what host/port *is* your MySQL on? Is the Android device on the same network?

Comment: 3306. I've mentioned that in the `connectionString` variable.

Comment: what happens if you use this one `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?user=root&password=password01`?

Comment: have you seen this link? [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: Does your MySQL server allow remote connections?

Comment: @JW. : if I write `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?user=root&password=password01`, I get `Connection refused`.

Comment: @JW. : that vogella tutorial suggests similar to what I have done. But it uses only `localhost` (without port number).

Comment: @GGeorge : how to check whether mysql server allows remote connections?

Comment: Have you confirmed your ability to connect, using the `mysql` command line client (mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=password01)?

Comment: @GAMA See Perception's response. :) Is your server locally or remotely?

Comment: locally. And I have also allowed remote connections (if it means granting privileges)?

Comment: by using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@192.168.1.104 IDENTIFIED BY 'password01';`

Comment: @Perception & GGeorge : **YES**, when i use above credentials, it's giving desired output on command line.

Comment: Also, I didn't find any `my.cnf` or `my.ini` in MySql directory. So I created `my.cnf` at *C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin* manually. I set `bind-address="127.0.0.1"` and commented `skip-networking`. Is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is android application is on same ntework? If not

> jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.104:3306

and

> jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.0:3306

will not work.

Give the proper network address of mysql.

Comment: Please have a look at question. I've tried 5 different combinations for specifying network address and corresponding issue.

Comment: if application is on the same address then 192.168.104 approach should work fine. You should look at this post in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Comment: m getting `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out` if I use `192.168.1.104:3306`....

Comment: `connectionString =
   "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.104:3306/dbname?user=root&password=password01";` worked...

Answer (score 1):

I use **latest version of adt** and **mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar**, this works for me :

Add the below code into your file after the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

and use `import android.os.StrictMode;`

If you use new api, add `@SuppressLint("NewApi");`