# Jenkins - Running selenium IDE test suite on node causes ReadSocketTimeoutException

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jetty, selenium-ide

I have a set of Selenium IDE test suites which are periodically triggered via Jenkins and set to run on a remote node. My issue here is that all of these tests execute as expected when I run them locally via the Firefox Selenium IDE plugin, but they often timeout and fail when executed by these Jenkins jobs. On my selenium.log, I get the following error before the job is forced to fail by the explicitly determined timeout setting:

`08:29:24.961 DEBUG [17] org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

Which leads me to believe that these fails are not related to the tests themselves, but instead, there is something going within this node in which the Jetty container is complaining about the maxIdleTime or something down those lines. If so, how can I increase/manage this maxIdleTime setting?

By the way, I am not including the console log because the only useful item there is the failure triggered by the absolute timeout setting.

Thanks.

Comment: There are various maxIdleTime settings in Jetty, for client libs, websocket, and all of the various connectors and endpoints too.  A little bit more detail would be of help.

Comment: I found what my problem was here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/585643/1642169