# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset issue

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, tcp, socketexception

I have been experiencing an issue with a web application, the application throws the  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception. I believe this exception is thrown because the client has closed the connection before the response is sent back from the server. I could not recreate this issue in the development environment with the same settings. It works fine after I restart tomcat but the app starts throwing this exception after a certain time. I suspect the way I am managing my db connection pool but have not been able to recreate this issue as I have mentioned before.

```
 org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:625) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:904) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at edu.ucla.iamucla.tools.shibboleth.manager.dao.hibernate.ApplicationGroupDaoHibernate.getAllApplicationGroups(ApplicationGroupDaoHibernate.java:73) ~[ApplicationGroupDaoHibernate.class:na]
    at edu.ucla.iamucla.tools.shibboleth.manager.web.HomeController.getApplicationGroups(HomeController.java:74) ~[HomeController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710) ~[spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:152) ~[spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716) ~[spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647) [spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552) [spring-webmvc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) [catalina.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [na:1.6.0_19]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406) ~[spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1053) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.microsoftPrepare(TdsCore.java:1179) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.prepareSQL(ConnectionJDBC2.java:693) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:777) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213) ~[hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:178) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:152) ~[na:1.6.0_19]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:842) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:723) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:466) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:103) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.peek(ResponseStream.java:88) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.wait(TdsCore.java:3932) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.executeSQL(TdsCore.java:1046) ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

The previous developer was writing the log to the console which is resulting in a very big catalina.out file. I am not sure how that can cause the exception but that's the only thing I see that's odd. Following is my db configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName.sqlserver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url.sqlserver}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username.sqlserver}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password.sqlserver}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.pool.maxActive}" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="${jdbc.pool.maxWait}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.pool.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${jdbc.pool.maxIdle}" />

    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>


</bean>
```

I would be glad if someone could shed some light on this issue, I am using Spring 3.x , Hibernate, SQL Server , tomcat6.

Comment: "I believe this exception is thrown because the client has closed the connection" <-- your logs say the opposite: it is the _server_ which has closed the connection here (SQL Server, that is)

Comment: I think it's more so a client side issue than the server side one. The way to find out would be through wireshark or tcpdump

Comment: we did install wireshark the other day and are monitoring the network.The other thing I wanted to mention is, the application has been in production was almost two years now and we have been experiencing this issue from the past couple of months.

Comment: Server/firewall etc. closing pooled connections before the client? Try enabling connection testing (testOnBorrow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's causing my java.net.SocketException: Connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)