# Spring Data MongoDB - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

Getting an error like in the title when I try to persist data on MongoDB using **Spring Data MongoDB**.

Here's my configuration:

```
<!-- Mongo Configuration -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.tk.detective" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- local config -->
    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="detective" host="dbserver" port="27017" mongo-ref="mongoRef"/>

    <mongo:mongo id="mongoRef" host="dbserver" port="27017">
        <mongo:options connections-per-host="100" threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="50" connect-timeout="1000" max-wait-time="2500"
                       auto-connect-retry="true" socket-keep-alive="true" socket-timeout="15000" slave-ok="true" />
    </mongo:mongo>
```

Getting error when I try to save any objects:

```
mongoTemplate.save(object);
```

**Full error stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Write operation to server dbserver/xxx.xx.xx.xx:27017 failed on database detective

at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:153) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:248) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:148) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:91) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:810) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:786) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:884) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.pipe(PoolOutputBuffer.java:129) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.pipe(OutMessage.java:236) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:133) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:102) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:97) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:140) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.11.2.jar:na]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score -1):

is dbserver your real hostname?

Is a firewall blocking it?

can you get to mongodb from command line?  from a GUI client?

See:  [What's causing my java.net.SocketException: Connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Comment: yeah I'm able to connect Mongo via a third party application. By the way dbserver is the hostname of server of Mongo.