# Large messages failing in SoapUI - "Error getting response; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Tags: java, wcf, soapui

I'm using Soap UI 4.6.0 to hit a WCF web service, and when I have really large message payloads, I'm seeing the following error:

```
Error getting response; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

The WCF service has around 10 methods, each with progressively larger inputs (eg, 10 int properties, 50 int properties, 100 int properties, etc).   This works with the smaller messages, but as they get around 2000-3000 int properties, the error occurs.

The call *appears* to succeed on the server side, and with this coming from java, I'm assuming I'm butting up against some size limitation/configuration in the client.  Is this something I can tweak within Soap UI, the java runtime, or elsewhere?

Comment: What about checking / increasing the size of the message and buffer sizes for the bindings at the WCF side. What you also can do to troubleshoot further is enable some WCF logging, to see what is the server is trying to get returned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For me the trick that worked was adding below entry in SoapUI-5.2.0.vmoptions file (it can be found in the bin directory of installa

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2

Answer (score 1):

Normally a connection reset means that one of the underlying servers timed out waiting for data from another server/application and it reset the connection.

You should try out the suggestions @kroonwijk gave it'll tell you which server is causing the reset and what is causing the server to reset the connection.

Also see [What's causing my java.net.SocketException: Connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Answer (score -1):

If above solutions won't work for you then try this:

1. Close SoapUI
2. Go to SoapUi directory for example: C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\
3. Rename directory "jre" to "jre.ignore"
4. Done. Open SoapUi and it should work now.