# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am getting SocketException on following line. 
I have something like

```
    try{
        while(){
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ampletrails.com").timeout(300000).get();
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Java exception is thrown and program exit. How can I prevent this to continue in while loop and prevent program to exit.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2582)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:113)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:447)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:159)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:148)
    at base_class.main(base_class.java:20)
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/585643/738746) might apply, please take a look.

Comment: How can I prevent termination of this program?

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the server is sending a TCP `reset` to terminate the connection you are making.

If this is an intermittent connection, you could avoid a program exit by putting the try and catch blocks inside the while loop instead of outside.  It would be best to figure out why the server is resetting your connections, though.