# I get connection reset exception when I am trying to send mail from outlook web access

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have read multiple blogs for this topic but am not able to debug the error.
I am trying to send mail from my corporate outlook web access. Here is the code :

```
package ReadOutlook;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class email_readClass {      
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String username = "user1";
        final String password = "pass1";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "email.company.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "443");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user1@company.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("user1@company.com"));
            message.setSubject("Test");
            message.setText("HI");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception         reading response;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at ReadOutlook.email_readClass.main(email_readClass.java:45)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1462)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1260)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
at ReadOutlook.email_readClass.main(email_readClass.java:40)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:75)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1440)
... 8 more
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on the server?

Answer (score -1):

The Exception means that the socket was closed unexpectedly. See this [What's causing my java.net.SocketException: Connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I could not resolve this with the article which you mentioned though. The network I am in, uses a proxy. Could that be the reason for this error? If so, how do I get around that?

Comment: I checked again..I am trying to access corporate email, so no proxy is used.Can you suggest something?

Comment: check this for better understanding http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: Check this also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail

Comment: No, it doesn't mean the socket was closed, unexpectedly or otherwise. It means the *connection* was *aborted,* and the question is 'why?'