# Android Httpclient error: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I have an error when I try to send my location data using my android to my sql server. I used a service, httpclient and a loop-thread to send my data to my server. I believe that my network speed is slow.  Here is the code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!isRunning) {
        mythread.start();
        isRunning = true;
    }
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void accessWebPage() {

    try {
        busID = sp.getString("busNumber", "");
        ipadd = sp.getString("ipAddress", "");
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://" + ipadd
                + link+"?msg=ID" + busID + "%20TM" + time
                + "%20DT" + date + "%20LT" + latitude + "%20LN" + longitude
                + "%20AT" + altitude + "%20SP" + speed + "%20CO" + course));
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    static final long DELAY = 3000;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
                try {
                accessWebPage();
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: i think that's happening because your server response is to late or might be your connection is weak.

Comment: Is there a problem with my code? Or are there work around solutions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset check out this link it will give you brief idea.

Comment: Is a 3 second delay enough for this?

Comment: yeah as per my experience that is okay.

Comment: Thanks Aiyaz, let me ask also if my thread will continue even I got this socketException error?

Comment: no it won't be continue. cause thread can't throw checked exception but at here this is runtime exception so it will be thrown . so as i think it won't continue.