# jmeter: NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Tags: node.js, performance, jmeter, load-testing

I have an application in nodejs, which I am testing against thousands of users. For 1000 users (when server is deployed at local), Jmeter fails for most test cases providing this:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Sometimes, I get this as well:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried all the steps in this link:
https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed
None of them worked. (I am using Jmeter 2.13)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running your app server locally (I assume with moderate level of HW i.e. dual/quad core CPU, 4/8 GB RAM etc.) and running Jmeter instance on same server then you should understand below things,

1. As a rule of thumb you can assume Jmeter alone (with all [tuning settings](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) applied and enough rampup)can create 500-1000 threads with that hw.
2. You are running your app server on same machine with Jmeter. This means your app server is getting less resources to use. From errors it looks like that target server/app server is unable to handle that load.
3. This behavior is obvious because of many reasons like insufficient memory, over CPU utilization, IO issues, Jmeter is not coping with server.

What you can do is,

1. Try to deploy app server on separate machine with equal or better hw.
2. Follow all Jmeter best practices mentioned in above link.
3. Run the test and monitor resource utilization on both servers just to correlate the values with results.

Check if your test passes or not. (Even if it doesn't then at least you know that its not because of Jmeter :) and with the help of resource util logs, Jmeter logs you can find out the bottleneck.)

Similar question I found was [Why am I receiving Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745350/why-am-i-receiving-response-code-non-http-response-code-java-net-socketexcepti/30747112#30747112).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same - deployed the app on a different server and tried hitting it using Jmeter from local. The problem did not show up in this case.  But with this, is it possible to test 1000-5000 CONCURRENT users?

Comment: It depends on your server capability. If you server util logs and other perf counters monitored as I suggested then go through those logs check room for more load. If server can take that load then yes you can run test with 1000-5000 users. Instead of just hitting with 1000-5000-10000 load try to find out real life expected load on your app and then do it. Otherwise its just stress test.

Comment: Assuming the server can take up that load, can Jmeter that is running in a local machine execute 5000 threads simultaneously without hanging up? Doesn't that depend on my local machine's capabilty?

Comment: Yes of course :) It depends on settings in JMeter (heap size, jvm policy) and max capacity of your hw.

Comment: Please upvote or accpet answer if that was helpful so that it will community in future.

Answer (score 0):

when running maximum number of user, i hope you had taken care about various aspects of the run

- user ramp up time
- proper timers ( decent amount of think time must be provided)
- and most of all , the server that is being utilized should have capability to respond

for a given simple server ( which does not support multi-threading), when we send concurrent requests continuously, at a given point of time, we must analyse and conclude a healthy load , at a point when there are more number of requests being sent, the usual behavior is the script would make you run in errors ;)

Please recheck and post additional info.