# How to resolve java.net.socketexception connection reset error in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Configuration:`Jmeter 3.0` and `OS:Linux` `jdk:1.8`

When I run a https(REST Api) request, `View Results Tree` shows:

```
Response code:Non Http Response code:java.net.socketException

Response message:Connection Reset
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Share your request

Comment: 1 thread user and 1sec ramp up time, nothing more in it, same jmx file works well on windows system

Answer (score 1):

Change **`Implementation`** of all your **`HTTP Request`** samplers to `HttpClient4`.

Add the following properties in `user.properties` file which located under `/bin` folder of your JMeter installation:

```
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

Add the next line to `hc.parameters` file (same location, JMeter's `/bin` folder)

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
```

Restart JMeter.

- Additionally, `Use KeepAlive` checkbox in the `HTTP Request Sampler/Defaults`.

Also these [thread#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515741/jmeter-nohttpresponseexception-the-target-server-failed-to-respond) and [thread#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772952/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-error-in-net-application) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Connection reset might indicate an issue on the server side or in an intermediate component of your architecture.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31781529/460802