# Jenkins windows slaves keep disconnecting and after min reconnecting, repeatedly every few hours

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, disconnect

I'm using CentOS7 as my master (Jenkins version 2.46) and have many slaves connected to it with different OS. I've spotted a strange behavior with mine three Windows_7 slaves - they go offline every few hours and after minutes comes back online. With this error:

```
Connection was broken: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:86)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readHeader(ChunkedInputStream.java:72)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:103)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
```

After a minute or so it comes back to normal

```
executing pre-launch scripts ...
[2017-02-14 17:00:57] [windows-slaves] Connecting to 10.10.126.130
Checking if Java exists
java -version returned 1.7.0.
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Installing the Jenkins slave service
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Copying jenkins-slave.exe
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Copying slave.jar
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Copying jenkins-slave.xml
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Registering the service
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Starting the service
[2017-02-14 17:01:00] [windows-slaves] Waiting for the service to become ready
[2017-02-14 17:01:05] [windows-slaves] Connecting to port 49,253
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 3.4.1
This is a Windows agent
just before slave CCG-WIN7-VS2008 gets online ...
executing prepare script ...
setting up slave CCG-WIN7-VS2008 ...
slave setup done.
Scheduled overwrite of jenkins-slave.exe on the next service startup
Agent successfully connected and online
```

I started getting this problem after moving these slaves from DHCP to static IP's. And only Windows slaves have this problem, all other OS's are working as they should.
They build projects so there is no problem there, but constant spam of email of disconnect and connect is a bit annoying.

Comment: Did you see the following questions referring to `Connection reset`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset ?

Comment: Thanks allot @GeroldBroser, no I didn't c that posts before