# How to resolve Connection Reset issue in Google calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using java and google calendar API to insert/update/delete events from my google calendar. It is working fine.. At times it throws Connection Reset error when writing or updating the event via API.

Is there any possibility to resolve this issue.?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If this is a java code, maybe the SO Posts below can help you determine what's wrong and where did you messed up in your code. Since I am not sure what code you are using, I'll give you an example where this error always occur.

1. [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406275/getting-error-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

> "Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection
>   reset" error occurs when the opponent is forcibly terminated without
>   calling close().

Maybe there is something in your code that forced the opponent to be terminated without calling the `close()` function.

If that's the case, you can add this two line in both

Client

```
skt.close();
```

and ServerSock

```
ss.close();
```

> *Note: java.io.Closeable implementing object must call close ().*

2. [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

javadoc for SocketException states that

> Thrown to indicate that there is an error in the underlying protocol
>   such as a TCP error

The connection in the server end maybe closed and caused the issue when sending the issue at their end.

> To aid debugging you could look at using a tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to
>   view the actual network packets. Also, is there an alternative client
>   to your Java code that you could use to test the web service? If this
>   was successful it could indicate a bug in the Java code.
>
> As you are using Commons HTTP Client have a look at the [Common HTTP
>   Client Logging Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html). This will tell you how to log the request at the
>   HTTP level.

Hope 1 of these two answers will help you.