# connection reset error while testing the App on simulator

Tags: codenameone

I see the following error during the login process while calling REST methods with JSON response. Please advise what would be causing this issue in simulator.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
[Network Thread] 0:5:5,328 - Exception during JSON parsing at row: 1 column: 32593 buffer: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QAiRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAQESAAMAAAABAAEAAAAAAAD  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
SxZN3Hpvl3GnzbbeF920jPJ4wfXrUlxrU1/rkc1k0djqWMROQCOevtWJceIrGzidmVWjYcKGz81MHiXSXtoWv1mJjOUAUjP4ivr5YqkqTUmjxsLRqc6bTPuL/g3Lik0n/gr5pNtqzLdam+4rMowB+
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
fD+TxB46uLjwiftXlGxu2aCfy8ZyFNfL5txNh6MXFSVz6rLMkqStKorH0B/wQT/4JUfCn9vn9hm81zxNDdLf2utGISwBdxATOCTX20/8AwbcfAkhfk1LKjByE5/Svoz/gnD+wZ4f/AOCeP7PFn4F0GSSRVYT3MjEZklxgmvoDdk
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3393)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:445)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser$ReaderClass.read(JSONParser.java:124)
/Xn4dkY6DZbuW+zx5PvtFVhsT7VXPHz7JXl1VUpF0fLnnNAfJpucE0K2UrqPCJK/MH/g6wH/ABrus/bWV/8AQDX6eb8ivzD/AODrP/lHfY5bH/E5X8fkNZ1PgZ15ev8AaYep/OXpQVdN0/d/zwU1aYrJJ7ZrNspN2k2OG+byV/K
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:194)
```

Comment: I'll need more details about how this connection was made to help but I would suggest reading this answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset