# Jmeter throwing "socketexception: connection reset" during the tests. But no error can be seen on server log

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

We tried running a performance test with 200 concurrent users over 8 machines. During the execution, "java.net.socketexception: Connection Reset" error was seen & the users started failing.

But when we checked the server log, there was no such errors can be seen. Also, the application was manually accessible and functioned normally without any issue during the execution as well.

Is this an issue at server level or an issue from jmeter end? Need help in this. Using Jmeter 5.3 version

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62929/3124333) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/585599/3124333) and probably others.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In neither of those 2, the errors were not showing at the logs. It is showing there...In my case, no errors can be seen in logs and they can only be seen at jmeter level. thats the issue