# "System.Net.WebException: Connection reset" error in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui, .net-7.0

```
{System.Net.WebException: Connection reset
 ---> Java.Net.SocketException: Connection reset
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 11725
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualInt32Method(String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:line 511
   at Java.Net.HttpURLConnection.get_ResponseCode() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.Net.HttpURLConnection.cs:line 511
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.<>c__DisplayClass132_0.<DoProcessRequest>b__2() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 577
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Net.HttpStatusCode, System.Net.Primitives, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__273_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, URL javaUrl, HttpURLConnection httpConnection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestRedirectionState redirectState) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 577
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 417
  --- End of managed Java.Net.SocketException stack trace ---
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:215)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:188)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:129)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:750)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:622)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)

  --- End of managed Java.Net.SocketException stack trace ---
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:215)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:188)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:129)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:750)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:622)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler.DoSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidMessageHandler.cs:line 431
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Kuber.UI.Services.HttpClientService.<SendAsync>d__2`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext() in C:\Github\Kuber.UI\Kuber.UI\Services\Concrete\HttpClientService.cs:line 32}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxhy6.png)

I am sending "JsonCryption.Encryption" and "JsonCryption.Decryption" encryption algorithms in encrypted json model.

When I tested my api published on win server, it was working without any problems. But after the server was shut down, I republished it with the domain over local IIS. But I can't send requests anymore because it gives this error. It was giving an error when I raised the api locally via visual studio. later i tried this method and i started getting this error.

```
public async Task<ResponseModel<TEntity>> SendAsync<TEntity>(HttpMethod method, string requestUri, object content)
{
    try
    {
        var url = new Uri(App.KuberURL + requestUri);
        var request = new RequestModel
        {
            model = JsonCryption.Encryption(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content))
        };
        var cryptionContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
        httpRequestMessage.Content = cryptionContent;
        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel<TEntity>>(JsonCryption.Decryption(json));

        return responseModel;
    }
    catch(TimeoutException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
        //throw new Exception();
    }
}
public class ResponseModel<TEntity>
{
    public TEntity Value { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there are numerous existing posts about this error.  Please search before posting

Comment: I tried all the problems, but it didn't work

Comment: You can check this link about [What's causing my java.net.SocketException: Connection reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset).