# Java socket timeout during read

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, timeout

What happens if a client connected through a `Socket` has a bad lag ?
Let's say i call `socket.read()` from the TCP server, and the client writes some stuff on the network pipe, but his connection is laging for 1 or 2 minutes. What will happen ? Will the `read` fail ? Or will it wait ?

I'm not sure if it's even possible, but i'm playing online chess on FICS server and sometimes it seems to happen from my point of view (I'm only a user of this chess server).

I'm asking this because i'm working on an online game and i'd like to handle such cases one way or another. But first I need to know if:

- it can happen
- it can be detected

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise not relying solely on setting the `SO_TIMEOUT` variable but rather add application-level heartbeats between your client and server.  If either the client or server does not receive a heartbeat message within a specified time (e.g. within twice the heartbeat frequency) it should sever the connection, and in the client's case attempt a reconnect.

Using a heartbeat mechanism also allows you to measure the lag by monitoring the delay in receiving heartbeat messages on each end.

Comment: i'm just thinking... it's too bad it was not included in plain TCP

Comment: Yes it is frustrating but I can understand why it's not part of the protocol, as different applications have different requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The `read()`-method will block. But there is the [`setSoTimeout()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) which can be used to set a timeout that can be handled.

Comment: I'm aware of this option but how can it help distinguishing a lag from an absence of activity ?

Comment: I don't think you can. You can buffer a lag using the Timeout and if there is no response, you'll need to assume there isn't anything coming in from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using `setSoTimeout()` might be a bit misleading. When you use it in such manner:

```
Socket sock = new Socket(host, port);
sock.setSoTimeout(3000); // 3 seconds timeout
```

The constructor initiates the connect(), while timeout haven't been set. Instead of expected 3 second timeout you get the default one. To get the desired timeout you can do it following way:

```
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.connect(sockaddr, 3000); // 3 seconds timeout
```