# why connection reset problem is come

Tags: java, sockets, exception

When I try to use sockets in my Java application, I get a `SocketException`:

```
  SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:200)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2559)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2569)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at Form.Server.transfer(Server.java:69)
    at Form.Server.main(Server.java:53)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Answer (score 1):

[java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)