# Axis web service client error

Tags: java, web-services, axis, socketexception

One of our customers faced this error while calling our web service.

I think this is because a connection problems from his side, but I need to know the exact reason.

Stack trace:

```
Error while calling 10108831-402TV04LF from Thread 1 occurred after 511441
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)

        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at ABCWebService.ABCSearchWebserviceSoapHttpStub.getABCWebServiceData(ABCSearchWebserviceSoapHttpStub.java:206)
        at ABCWebService.ABCSearchWebserviceProxy.getABCWebServiceData(ABCSearchWebserviceProxy.java:50)
        at main.VericalWsThread.run(VericalWsThread.java:66)

        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:WIN-IUMHLP6L0NU

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)

        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at ABCWebService.ABCSearchWebserviceSoapHttpStub.getABCWebServiceData(ABCSearchWebserviceSoapHttpStub.java:206)
        at ABCWebService.ABCSearchWebserviceProxy.getABCWebServiceData(ABCSearchWebserviceProxy.java:50)
        at main.VericalWsThread.run(VericalWsThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)

        ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31741436/2046462) explains the possibility of the error. And the answers to the question provides more details about the error.
[This link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2316?focusedCommentId=14131498&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14131498) provides a solution which will fix when the error happens when the connection is timed out.