# BufferedReader reading from socket

Tags: java, sockets, connection, bufferedreader

I have a bufferedreader and for some reason it wont read the text from the print stream I am sending from my client. This is the point at which it fails every time the line = in.readline

Also I have checked and the server is connected.

This is the error

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at Server.ServerListener$getXML.run(ServerListener.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Thanks in advance

```
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new       InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
            //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Start");
            //read the xml
           boolean connected = server.isConnected();
            System.out.println("xml: "+ connected);
            line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Postread");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {               
                System.out.println("while1");
                xml = xml + line;
                System.out.println("while2");
            }`
```

Comment: You need to post the writing code as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isConnected() tells you whether your socket is connected to the connection, not whether the connection is still connected to the peer. Obviously you *aren't* still connected at all. 'Connection reset' has several possible causes: you wrote to a connection that had already been closed by the other end (application protocol error); the other end aborted the connection; the local TCP stack has encountered network errors sending and has given up. First of those is then most likely suspect. And don't use PrintStreams/Writers across the network, as they swallow exceptions you need to know about. And you are throwing away a line of data with the first readLine() call: remove it and just leave the one in the loop.