# Java server , client program

Tags: java, client-server

The code below should allow the user to enter a URL and have it return the ip address of that website but it's not working.

The application is a console application. I had it working at one time but I don't know why it won't work now.

Here is the error i am getting when the users enters a website to get the ip address from

```
IOException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

HERE IS MY CLIENT CODE

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String hostname = "localhost";
        int port = 6052;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            hostname = args[0];
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        PrintWriter os = null;
        BufferedReader is = null;


        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
            os = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            is = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + hostname);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + hostname);
        }


        if (clientSocket == null || os == null || is == null) {
            System.err.println("Something is  really wrong. ");
            return;
        }

        try {
            if (args.length != 2) {

                System.out.print("Enter a www web address (must have www!) ");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputSreamReader(Sy.in))
                String keyboardInput = br.readLine();
                os.println(keyboardInput);

            } else {
                os.println(args[1]);
            }
            String responseLine = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("The IP address of " + args[1] + "is" + responseLine);


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Trying to connect to host: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

HERE IS MY SERVER CODE

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int port = 6052;
        Server server = new Server(port);
        server.startServer();
    }

    ServerSocket echoServer = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    int numConnections = 0;
    int port;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        System.out.println("Server working hold on a min.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void startServer() {
        try {
            echoServer = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Server is now started and is waiting for Clients.");


        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
                numConnections++;
                new Thread(new ServerConnection(clientSocket, numConnections,
                        this)).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}




 class ServerConnection implements Runnable {
 private static BufferedReader is;
 private static PrintStream os;
 private static Socket clientSocket;
 private static int id;
 private static Server server;

 public ServerConnection(Socket clientSocket, int id, Server server) {
this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
this.id = id;
this.server = server;
System.out.println( "Connection " + id + " established with: " + clientSocket );
try {
    is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
}




public void run() {
    String line;
try {
    boolean serverStop = false;

            line = is.readLine();
    System.out.println( "Received " + line + " from Connection " + id + "." );

                 InetAddress hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(line);
                 String IPaddress = hostAddress.getHostAddress();
                 os.println(IPaddress);

          is.close();
        os.close();
     clientSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" please provide some specific information, like the errors you are getting or anything that can help answer your question

Comment: ...also, I do not mind editing, but a little spell checking and proper code formatting would help

Comment: i added what error im getting

Comment: i get this error when the user enters a website to get the ip address from. then i get this error                       IOException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Also, the verification of `args` is not good. I compiled your code and got `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` when running `Client` without arguments. But could not reproduce a `SocketException`.

Comment: What are your command line arguments. We can't see the stack trace on the code. Post the stack trace given when you run with the error.

Comment: yea the arrayOutOfBounds ex is no big deal i just never test a blank input.

Comment: i can fix that problem easily, i just cant get around the other execption its throwing

Comment: Again, what are the command line arguments you're using and what is the stack trace when the problem occurs?

Comment: yea i dont know how to do that,

Comment: use jgrasp or eclipse if you want to

Comment: in the command line i enter javac Server.java     javac Client.java  then i run them java Server      java Client

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Client.main(Client.java:66)

Comment: Ok. Then you run `Client` without arguments. With program running, what are the values you input?

Comment: This array out of bounds is because you didn't verify `args` well (as I said before).

Comment: if no args on CLient u get this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Client.main(Client.java:66)

Comment: and with args u get this error      IOException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Man, I don't wanna be repetitive, but **what are the args you put when you get the error?** Write the command you call `Client`, for example `$ java Client this_is_argument_1 this_is_argument_2`.

Comment: when i enter www.google.com or any other website.

Comment: that is when the error happens when the users enters a website to get the ip address of it, then the program crashes

Comment: The firs argument is the host where server is running.

Answer (score 1):

With no arguments, host will be `localhost`, user will be propted for a website. `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because you didn't check the arguments.

With one argument, it is the host. Passing a site will not work because the site won't work as expected.

Running with two arguments, it works if the first argument is `localhost`.

Comment: Check the arguments only in beginning of the program. Make the first argument be the hostname and the second the website. If one or both are not present, handle it properly.

Comment: ok so i ran my code in eclipse this is every thing that happen ,  first "Server is now started and is waiting for Clients."    sencond Enter a www web address (must have www!) then users enters www.google.com then i get this error IOException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Comment: Run it from terminal. One terminal for each class (`Server` then `Client`).