# Connection reset error when reading data from client java

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing Client-Server App using Java Socket. My Application Has Server which will listen on Port

- Client will connect to that port
- Receive Data From Client
- Send Data To Client

Part of My Code

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Got a client !");
    try {
        // Get Data From Client
        int red = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5 * 1024]; // a read buffer of 5KiB
        byte[] redData;
        StringBuilder clientData = new StringBuilder();
        String redDataText;
        while ((red = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > -1) {

/* Get Data From Client Here Code Hidden */

            System.out.println("Data From Client :"
                    + clientData.toString());

            OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

            String sDataToClient = "TEST DATA TO SEND IN BYTE ARRAY";

            byte[] b = sDataToClient.getBytes("UTF-8");

            byte[] bClientSend = new byte[b.length + 2];

            bClientSend[0] = (byte) 1;
            bClientSend[1] = (byte) 79;

            System.arraycopy(b, 0, bClientSend, 2, b.length);

            dos.write(bClientSend);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bClientSend));

        }
        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I Get `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` after Data SENT to Client at following line**

```
while ((red = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > -1) {
```

**I am able to see Array Contents of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bClientSend));` Then error occurs**

Comment: Did you close the connection at the server side? Look at possible causes for the exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Comment: visited link before... is it because after Sending Data to client My Client Closes connection with server and hence i get error in `while` loop ?

Comment: My Server doesnt close the connection with client

Comment: Try to use a BufferedInputStream instance and use that in the loop condition.

Comment: just to be sure if a more basic socket program worked for you ? I mean is this your first socket program ?

Comment: Your *client* has probably closed the connection while you were still writing to it. See my answer to the duplicate post quoted in Ganesh's answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quoting a duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

> > There are several possible causes.
>
> The other end has deliberately reset the connection, in a way which I
>   will not document here. It is rare, and generally incorrect, for
>   application software to do this, but it is not unknown for commercial
>   software.
>
> More commonly, it is caused by writing to a connection that the other
>   end has already closed normally. In other words an application
>   protocol error.
>
> In Windows, 'software caused connection abort', which is not the same
>   as 'connection reset', is caused by network problems sending from your
>   end. There's a Microsoft knowledge base article about this.