# Using cassandra-cli connecting to thrift port

Tags: linux, networking, cassandra

Sorry I'm relatively new to Cassandra DB.

I have bound cassandra to my eth0 IP as rpc_address
I have bound the port to 9160 for rpc_port
I start cassandra and the process shows as running just fine:

```
[root@kc-broker ~]# lsof -i tcp:9160
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    8480 root   35u  IPv4  39282      0t0  TCP localhost:apani1 (LISTEN)
java    8480 root   91u  IPv4  38641      0t0  TCP kc-broker.dsx.org:apani1 (LISTEN)
```

So I run the cassandra-cli command and get this error:

```
[dsxcore-dsx.dsx.org 52851c6e8000fdf616000015]\> ./cassandra/versions/1.2.5/bin/cassandra-cli -h localhost -p 9160
    Exception retrieving information about the cassandra node, check you have connected to the thrift port.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1101)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1089)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:147)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:246)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
... 12 more
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.2.5

Type 'help;' or '?' for help.
Type 'quit;' or 'exit;' to quit.

[default@unknown] exit
```

Comment: Can you connect with cqlsh? Getting the IP wrong should lead to `java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out` and getting the port should lead to `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`. Also a reset connection [might mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset/4300803#4300803) C* crashed.

Comment: Did you find out a reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

An intermediate firewall is blocking the JVM from making the connection. An operating system firewall, or antivirus that is causing the problems as well. I think you installed in windows and looks like firewall is blocking your connection.