# Apache CXF Could not send message

Tags: java, apache, cxf

im having a random error of could not send message. sometimes there's no error.

what might be the cause?? thanks.

```
Mar 06, 2014 6:11:13 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {XXX }SoapApiServiceHttpEndpoint#{XXX}createSession has thrown exception, unwin
ding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: SocketException invoking : Connection reset
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2332.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Connection reset means that the client abnormally closed the connection and then cxf cannot read or write any further data to the stream. Take a look at following answers for more information:[java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)