# java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset. How do I stop this?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, tcp

Every time I close my TCP Server, on my clients, I get this exception:

> ```
>     java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2473)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2543)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2615)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2764)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
>       at client.ListenFromServer.run(ListenFromServer.java:33)
> ```

Here's my two pieces of code, one is my TCPClient which connects to the server through a socket, and also creates a listener to listen to messages from the server:

TCPClient.java:
http://pastie.org/private/msbnuhxyevxjlsdq1wvhow

ListenForServer.java:
http://pastie.org/private/pav4azrakgfz31culrrg2a

How do I stop this exception from happening? In my while loop in ListenForServer.java, I make a check to see if the socket is closed, and if it is, I break out of the loop, yet I'm still getting this exception.

What's the best way to catch it, because my program does not close properly when I exit it, I have to manually close it from within Netbeans IDE.

Comment: This contains different code and has a different outcome, clients remaining active when closed, having to be forced closed in netbeans ide. Still having trouble with this.

Comment: The code should be posted here. Otherwise the question has no permanent value and is liable for deletion.

Comment: The reason for this exception is [the same as it always is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4300803/207421).

Answer (score 2):

```
 In my while loop in ListenForServer.java, I make a check to see if the socket is closed, and if it is, I break out of the loop, yet I'm still getting this exception.
```

Yes you did but youre still listening to the inputstream when the socket was closed.

you need to catch the socket exception or change ur while loop