# I m getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception while running a load test using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, socketexception

I m running a load test on login page of my application for 100 users out of 100 20 users are passing rest 80 users i m getting the below exception , Kindly help me with the fix

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:505)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:328)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Answer (score 18):

I believe that you're facing the issue described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) JMeter wiki page. If you're **completely sure** that the behavior of your application under test is correct and nothing needs to be tuned or tweaked on the backend side you can configure JMeter to retry refused connections and check for stale connections:

1. Change "Implementation" of all your HTTP Request samplers to `HttpClient4`. The easiest way of doing it is using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults) configuration element.
2. Add the following properties in *user.properties* file which located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
3. Add the next line to *hc.parameters* file (same location, JMeter's /bin folder)

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```
4. Restart JMeter.

Your "Connection reset" problem should go away.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I too faced the above issue. I have done the steps you have mentioned, updated the Java 1.8 and checked the request are correct/not though but still, I am getting the same error. Please help me to resolve.

Comment: is it relevant for JMeter 3.3?