# Jmeter java.net.SocketException: Connection reset (after changing parameters)

Tags: jmeter, socketexception

Recently I'm working on performance script which will test 3rd party service.

Test is very simple, each thread need to POST one request.
Number of Threads - 100, 
Ramp Up - 680 s

While executing max number of active threads is 12.
I`m using Jmeter 3.2 version, but also tried on 2.1.

Unfortunately I'm obtaining `java.net.SocketException`: Connection reset error for 20-30% requests. Full error at the end of the post.

I`ve already change properties mentioned in many similar topics here (for example : [I m getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception while running a load test using Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789800/i-m-getting-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-exception-while-running-a)).

I've added:

```
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

in user properties

```
http.socket.timeout$Integer=120000 (such big value is set just for test reasons ;) )
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true in hc.parameters

httpclient.timeout=1200000 
httpclient4.idletimeout=1200000 (same as previous) in jmeter.properties
```

I've also changed HTTP Request Sampler default values in Advanced tab to:
`HTTPClient4` and both timeouts set to `120000`.

Note: So big test timeouts are related to the time that some of request can take on service side (even 10 minutes).

Unfortunately after all those changes, I`m still getting this error and people responsible for the service, after analysis answered that it is nothing on their side.

Full error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset;
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source);
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source);
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source);
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source);
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source);
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source);
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source);
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:158);
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82;
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:271);
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138);
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56);
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259);
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281);
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:199);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.receiveResponseHeader(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:212);
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273);
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125);
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684);
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486);
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835);
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:654);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:413);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189);
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178);
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491);
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425);
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254);
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source);
```

Comment: with 10 threads no error occurs?

Comment: Didn`t test with 10 threads, but while was looking at execution live (partial reports on console (non-GUI mode) errors came up even when less than 10 threads were active)

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others. thanks

Comment: I can't tell. My last try was to add keep-alive header to request, unfortunately tests were canelled and we are not authorized now to get response from service. There is a chance that tests will start again, in that case i'll provide update if it helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use JMeter 3.2 version.

Then try first manually the website, does it work correctly ?

If yes, run JMeter with 1 thread and check, if Connection Reset occur, then you most probably are not reproducing identically what browser does. In this case, record and try again.

If this only happens with many users, then your server is rejecting connection either due to an issue or a misconfiguration.

Comment: Thx for reply. It is only webservice, but checking it via postman for example works fine. Sending requests one by one do not show such errors. Issue occurs when more than 1 thread is active. What i can observe is when connection is reset, all currently active threads gets this error immediately. In request/response details i can see that "Size in bytes" property is 0 for those cases thats why i`m not sure if it isn`t problem on my side.

Comment: so it looks more lik a server issue

Comment: Hello, what update would you like ? I think you can accept answer no ? IMO it's a server issue but I would need an access to your env to be able to check.