# Getting "SocketException: Connection reset" error in Jmeter when try to hit a Post API call

Tags: jmeter, postman

I am trying to constuct a single API request using HTTP Request Sampler in JMeter, where the API payload has more than 5000 lines in it. After checking the request payload & headers, I tried to hit in JMeter, but it fails to respond back and thrown "SocketException: Connection reset" error.

Gone through this blog https://www.xtivia.com/blog/fixing-jmeter-socket-errors/ & tried to change the implementation to HTTPClient4 in the sampler after made the requested settings as mentioned here - [I m getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception while running a load test using Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789800/i-m-getting-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset-exception-while-running-a). But nothing helps with these options.

Same request (without any change) is working fine in Postman and gives expected response. Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to eliminate the eventual "copy-paste" issues try recording the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)
3. Import JMeter's certificate into Postman
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter should generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
6. You should now be able to replay the request in JMeter

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

In case of problems:

- add `javax.net.debug=all` line to *system.properties* file
- add the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
  <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug" />
  ```

  you will see way more troubleshooting information in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file. Unfortunately your "connection reset" message doesn't say a lot to us

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I have tried to record in the same way as you suggested. But again getting "Socket Exception" in JMeter while recording using Postman. Without JMeter proxy, Postman gives expected response. Is there something to be tweaked from JMeter end?

Comment: I don't know what can be tweaked because I don't see client and server side stacktraces. The only piece of advice I can provide so far is to untick `Use KeepAlive` for [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and/or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)