# Error getting response; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, wcf, soapui

I am getting this error when i am trying to test the wcf service using SoapUI 4.5.1.

Error log is as below:

> ```
>      java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
> at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpClientSupport.java:147)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:236)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:345)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:241)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

If i run the code by keeping debug point, then able to see the response but it is not binding to SoapUI.

I even tried by seting Socket Timeout = 0.

Please suggest me what this message means

Comment: Maybe here is the solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset ?