# Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) - Node.js - Azure File Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services, node.js-stream

We are try to create a service using node.js in Azure to download. We are sending writeStream in response.

Updated:

```
var option = new Object();
option.disableContentMD5Validation = true;
option.maximumExecutionTimeInMs = 20 * 60000;
fileService.getFileToStream(shareName, dirPath, fileName, response, option, function (error, result, response) {
    if(!error) {
        if(response.isSuccessful) {
      console.log("Success!");
  }
    }
});
```

While downloading files less than 4MB its working fine. But while downloading more than 4MB its giving error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at FileserviceTest.sendGET(FileserviceTest.java:58)
at FileserviceTest.main(FileserviceTest.java:18)
```

Below is the sample java client code.

```
    public static void sendGET() throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    URL obj = new URL("https://crowdtest-fileservice.azure-mobile.net/api/files/");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("sharename", "newamactashare");
    con.setRequestProperty("directorypath", "MaheshApp/TestLibrary/");
    con.setRequestProperty("filename", "Test.apk");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
        fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/uma.maheshwaran/Desktop/Test.mt");
        InputStream iin = con.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // declare 4KB buffer
        int len;

        // while we have availble data, continue downloading and storing to
        // local file
        while ((len = iin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        iin.close();
        fos.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println("Done");
    } else {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("GET request not worked");
    }

}
```

Can we convert write stream to buffer stream. If so how can we send that in response. Or is there any other way to send a large stream of data in response. Please help me on this. I am new to node.js.

Answer (score 3):

For getting File greater than 4MB from Azure File Storage, there is a request header `x-ms-range-get-content-md5` that it will cause the status code `400`(Bad Request) error, please refer to the `Get File` REST API doc of Azure File Storage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194274.aspx, see below:

[image]

So I reviewed the source of Azure File Storage SDK for Node (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/file/fileservice.js). For the function `getFileToText`, `getFileToLocalFile`, `createReadStream` and `getFileToStream`, you need to set the `options.disableContentMD5Validation` attribute to avoid the error, see below.

> - @param {boolean}            [options.disableContentMD5Validation]       When set to true, MD5 validation will be disabled when downloading files.

And refer to the source of `getFileToStream` as example:

[image]

In the NodeJS code, you need to add the code `response.disableContentMD5Validation = true;` at the front of invoking the function `getFileToStream`.

> Updated Code

```
// this sentence must be removed in Azure Mobile Service, it cause the error.
// response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// add the argument {disableContentMD5Validation: true}
fileService.getFileToStream(shareName, dirPath, fileName, response, {disableContentMD5Validation: true}, function (error, result, response) {
    if(!error) {
        if(response.isSuccessful) {
           console.log("Success!");
        }
    }
});
```

---

> Updated 2015-10-29: For Java Code:

The issue of Java exception is not related to Mobile Service Code. It was caused by missing a request header property called `X-ZUMO-APPLICATION` as below.

```
con.addRequestProperty("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "<Manage Access Key>");
```

You can find the key `<Manage Access Key>` at the bottom of Mobile Service Dashboard on Azure Portal, as the snapshot below:

[image]

Click the `MANAGE KEYS` button, you can see two keys as below:

[image]

Add the any one into the code, then the code works fine.

---

Server sample code in NodeJS for Azure Mobile Service：

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var azure = require('azure-storage');
    var fileService = azure.createFileService('<storage_account_name>','<storage_access_key>');
    fileService.getFileToStream('taskshare', 'taskdirectory', 'taskfile', response,{disableContentMD5Validation:true}, function(error, result, res) {
                if(!error) {
                  console.log(result);
                  console.log(res);
                }
    });
};
```

Client sample code in Java:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class MobileSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://<mobile_service_name>.azure-mobile.net/api/<api_name: example 'filestorage'>");
        HttpURLConnection https = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        https.addRequestProperty("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "<manage_access_key>");
        https.connect();
        int respCode = https.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(respCode);
        InputStream is = https.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, new FileOutputStream("<file_name>"));
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Please check the permission of the api in Azure Portal, see the picture below:

[image]

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Pan. I tried adding the above code in both the node.js and java codes. Still giving the same error. In the Azure mobile service log we got an error after adding this. "An unhandled exception occurred. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.". Please check the updated question for the detailed error.

Comment: @Sniper Sorry for my mistake of function arguments. I modified my code and tested it successfully on Azure Mobile Service. Please see my updated code.

Comment: @ Peter Pan - I tried the updated code but still I am facing the same "Connection reset - at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)" issue. I also tried to add maximumExecutionTimeInMs = 20 * 60000 in the option but no luck. Please check my updated code that I tried.

Comment: @Sniper The issue is not related to Mobile Service Code. It was caused by missing a request header property called `X-ZUMO-APPLICATION`. Please see the details at the updated post. And I think you need to recovery the complete content of the issue to help other people met the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Pan. Sure I will do that. I tried adding "x-zumo-application" and "x-zumo-master" in the request header, but still facing the same issue. Do we have to handle that headers in our node.js code or server will take care of it? Is there any specific clear documentations for fileservice using node.js. Or can you please provide us a sample client and server code which is working for?

Comment: @Sniper OK, please see the post updated of my sample client in Java and server in NodeJS. They are working.

Comment: @ Peter Pan. Its working fine if the network speed is high. But if the speed is bit slow (ex: 2G) is giving the same error. I tried adding "option.maximumExecutionTimeInMs = 20 * 60000;" in the option object. But no luck. Please check my updated code. Is there any way to increase the time out?

Comment: @Sniper I think you also need to set the client timeout thru HttpConnection code `con.setConnectTimeout(1000*30); //set timeout to 30 seconds` on the Java side.

Comment: Pan. Thank you for the great support. I have tried adding timeout in both client and server side but no luck. We are facing the same issue.  Please help us on this.

Comment: @Sniper What's the same issue? I didn't get any exception even without timout settings in both side. Could you supply more details? I'm pleasure for helping you.

Comment: Pan Its giving the error "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" if the network is slow while downloading.

Comment: @Sniper It's possible for unstable network. As references, there are two page explain some reasons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset and http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/tutorials-and-faqs/1871643-how-to-fix-internal-exception-java-net.