# How to find the root cause of Connection Reset in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

What this error means, how to get into root of it?

In SoupUI Log :

> ```
>    Tue Jan 05 10:55:32 CST 2016:ERROR:Exception in request: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>    Tue Jan 05 10:55:32 CST 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [Connection reset], see error log for details
> ```

In error log:

> ```
>    Tue Jan 05 10:55:32 CST 2016:ERROR:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
> at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
> at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.flush(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:102)
> at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:69)
> at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
> at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
> at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
> at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:113)
> at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
> at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:247)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:362)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:324)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:237)
> at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:127)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

I am providing Authorization - Basic 
and User name and pwd as well.

Using 5.0.0 SoapUI version.

Please suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset - see if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this in SoapUI:

go to preference->HTTP Settings ->Socket Timeout(ms) -> Set some value here

Your Error Log:

```
ERROR:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) suggests
```

-> Flushing Issue in you application
-> You are reading from Server where server has already closed the initial socket connection