# Getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, exception, socketexception

I am trying to execute a simple Client/Server program.But whenever i am trying to execute , i am getting "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" . why this exception occurs ? Any suggestion for me ?

Here is the code

SocServer.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Server is started");

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8886);

    System.out.println("Server is waiting for client request");

    Socket s = ss.accept();

    System.out.println("Client Connected");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    String str = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Client Data" + str);
```

}

SocketClient.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 8886;
    Socket s = new Socket(ip,port);

    String str = "Noman";

    OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os);

    os.write(str);
    os.flush();
}
```

Comment: 2 things: 1) you are assuming all of the data is present and accounted for on the `readLine` in 1SocServer.java` and 2) you never close any of the streams. Please review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset?rq=1

Comment: You do not send a newline while the listener is expecting one to unblock. Outside the completely unused PrintWriter (I discourage to use it ... better explicitly send newlines as they are expected). For a start try `String str = "Noman\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons

- The other end has deliberately reset the connection, in a way which I
  will not document here. It is rare, and generally incorrect, for
  application software to do this, but it is not unknown for commercial
  software

.

- More commonly, it is caused by writing to a connection that the other
  end has already closed normally. In other words an application
  protocol error.
- It can also be caused by closing a socket when there is unread data
  in the socket receive buffer.
- In Windows, 'software caused connection abort', which is not the same
  as 'connection reset', is caused by network problems sending from
  your end. There's a Microsoft knowledge base article about this.