# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when i run from android studio, but works in eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting the below exception when I run TestUtil class from android studio. But if I run it from eclipse it works fine.

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at com.XYZ.android.cmpi.util.RestUtil.get(RestUtil.java:36)
>       at com.XYZ.android.cmpi.tests.TestUtil.main(TestUtil.java:15)

```
public class TestUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        String response = RestUtil.get(new URL(RestUtil.getURL()));
        print(response);
    }

    public static void print(Object o) {
        out.print(o);
    }
}
```

//

```
  public class RestUtil {



        public final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

        public static String get(URL url) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public static String getURL() {
            // returns URL
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this exception when I run from android studio, but not from Eclipse.

Comment: See the answer of EJP about reasons for the "SocketException: Connection reset": http://stackoverflow.com/a/4300803/5031358

Comment: This is something related to android studio. Its failing only when i run TestUtil from android studio, but works fine in eclipse.