# How to enable TLS 1.2 in Java 7

Tags: java, jboss, java-7, tls1.2

I am trying to enable TLS 1.2 in my web app which uses JBoss 6.4 and Java 1.7. I have `-Dhttp.protocols = TLSv1.2` in my application environment but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Is there anything I could do to enable TLS 1.2?

I wrote a simple program

```
context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(null,null,null);
SSLContext.setDefault(context); 
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)context.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();
protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();
```

After running this program within the app the TLS 1.2 gets enabled. I do not want to run this program but I want to directly enable it during app startup. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: sysprop `https.protocols` only works if spelled with both s's and only for connections made with `URL.openConnection` not some other means like `SSLSocketFactory`

Answer (score 49):

There are many suggestions but I found two of them most common.

#### Re. JAVA_OPTS

I first tried `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"` on command line before startup of program but it didn't work for me.

#### Re. constructor

Then I added the following code in the startup class constructor and it worked for me.

```
try {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        ctx.init(null, null, null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Frankly, I don't know in detail why `ctx.init(null, null, null);` but all (SSL/TLS) is working fine for me.

### Re. System.setProperty

There is one more option: `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`. It will also go in code but I've not tried it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There seems to be a bug with the -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2" property as java opts in Java 7_80.

Comment: I also tried with Java options (eg. https.protocols) and did not work - it seemed like it didn't even look at the option.

Comment: I've tried searching the web, is there any evidence of this being a bug @karnesJ.R? I am working with Java 7_51 and I have the same problem, this solution also worked for me.

Comment: for me System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"); works! in java version 1.7.0_80

Answer (score 26):

You can upgrade your Java 7 version to 1.7.0_131-b31

For JRE 1.7.0_131-b31 in Oracle site :

> TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.1 are now enabled by default on the TLS client
>   end-points. This is similar behavior to what already happens in JDK 8
>   releases.

Comment: Can you please share a link to this?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u131-relnotes-3338543.html

Comment: Its a page with release notes. How do I download the jdk?

Comment: @UdayReddy you need to be a bussiness user to download.

Comment: It worked for me with the non business version jdk1.7.0_80 - but I did have to add `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` as Ankit and Meeraj suggested

Comment: I confirm that it work with jdk1.7.0_80, just remember to compile the classes with this jdk.

Answer (score 17):

Add following option for java application:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Comment: I have a question, what does this change do? Does it enable TLS for all incoming and outbound connection requests? Is there a way to log the TLS handshake?

Answer (score 9):

Add this parameter to `JAVA_OPTS` or to the command line in Maven:
`-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Answer (score 7):

`System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");` worked in my case. Have you checked that within the application?

Comment: this is a COTS product. i cannot use that. atleast i dont know how to use that when a system starts

Comment: Have you checked https://developer.jboss.org/thread/251967?start=0&tstart=0 in that case ?

Answer (score 6):

The stated answers are correct, but I'm just sharing one additional gotcha that was applicable to my case: in addition to using `setProtocol`/`withProtocol`, you may have some nasty jars that won't go away even if have the right jars plus an old one:

## Remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

## Retain

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Java is backward compatible, but most libraries are not. Each day that passes the more I wish shared libraries were outlawed with this lack of accountability.

## Further info

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Sridhar, So with these changes along with Dhttp.protocols = TLSv1.2 does 1.7.0_80 support TLSv1.2 by default (as I'm seeing sslHandshake is using TLSv1) or do I need to upgrade our JDK to later versions ? even when I provide '-Dhttps.protocols = TLSv1.2' in eclipse runtime env. or 'https.protocols = TLSv1.2' in catalina properties - it's not working!!

Comment: I feel your pain. I understand that upgrading is not possible in all situations. It does work for me on java 7 but I needed my architect to find out this unwanted jar.

Comment: Yes thanks for suggestion, but somehow it didn't work for me, same happens each time it defaults to TLSv1.

Answer (score 2):

To force enable TLSv1.2 in JRE7u_80 I had to use following code snippet before creating JDBC connection.

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Provider;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContextSpi;
import sun.security.jca.GetInstance;
import sun.security.jca.ProviderList;
import sun.security.jca.Providers;

public static void enableTLSv12ForMssqlJdbc() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    ProviderList providerList = Providers.getProviderList();
    GetInstance.Instance instance = GetInstance.getInstance("SSLContext", SSLContextSpi.class, "TLS");
    for (Provider provider : providerList.providers())
    {
        if (provider == instance.provider)
        {
            provider.put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLS", "TLSv1.2");
        }
    }
}
```

Able to connect to Windows 10 with SQL server 2017 & TLSv1.2 enabled OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be looking to the configuration that controls the underlying platform TLS implementation via `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2`.

Comment: Seems like it will only work with JDK 1.7.0_95 or later, but issue here is last public release/update on JDK 1.7 is JDK 1.7.0_80, So technically this works for who ever using a version of JDK having Oracle Support or an Oracle customer!! Please let me know if it works for JDK 1.7.0_80

Comment: This works with Azul Zulu OpenJDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when connecting to RDS Oracle even when client and server were both set to TLSv1.2 the certs was right and java was 1.8.0_141
So Finally I had to apply patch at [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html)

After applying the patch the issue went away and connection went fine.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by using

```
Service.setSslSecurityProtocol(SSLSecurityProtocol.TLSv1_2);
```

Comment: I couldn't find the package for this line