# Problems when moving from the jetty server to the tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm really stuck with a problem

I have built an Axis 2 client running against an API using a .WSDL file. I have used a local jetty server when I have developed, but I need to move it over to a local tomcat server. When I moved my .war file to the local Tomcat, I get the following error. Can someone please give me some advice so I'm going in the right direction

```
SLL debug in tomcat:
http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 189
http-nio-8080-exec-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
http-nio-8080-exec-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called close()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

A

```
   INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.193 | Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://someurl.com/Service.svc]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.194 | org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.196 |   at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.197 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:99)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.198 |   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.199 |   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.201 |   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.204 |   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.205 |   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.206 |   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.207 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.executeMethod(HTTPSenderImpl.java:900)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.209 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.sendViaPost(HTTPSenderImpl.java:212)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.213 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:121)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.215 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:403)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.218 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:234)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.220 |   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.222 |   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.224 |   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.227 |   at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.229 |   at se.docpub.documentfolderservice.DocumentFolderServiceStub.loadFolder(DocumentFolderServiceStub.java:769)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.231 |   at se.soleilit.document_api.resources.DocumentResource.getPublishedFolder(DocumentResource.java:96)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.233 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.235 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.236 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.237 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.239 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.246 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.250 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.255 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.265 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.270 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.279 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.283 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.290 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.298 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.302 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.304 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.306 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.308 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.314 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.316 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.324 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.330 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.333 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.336 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.339 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.345 |   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.348 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.352 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.354 |   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.356 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.357 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.363 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.365 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.367 |   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.369 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.371 |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.373 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.375 |   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:28:59.376 |   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.224 |   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.532 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.534 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.535 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.537 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.539 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.541 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.542 | Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.543 |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.555 |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.558 |   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.560 |   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.573 |   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.590 |   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.593 |   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.618 |   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.621 |   at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.656 |   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.659 |   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.726 |   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:95)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/12/21 13:29:00.738 |   ... 63 more
```

Comment: Looks like the connection URL is just plain wrong? Did you mean it to be `https://someurl.com/Service.svc` ?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have replaced the url for this post on stack overflow,

The real URL is another

Comment: ok, can you at least ensure you have network connectivity between the server you're running this on and where you want to connect, using, e.g. something like `telnet` ? I'm asking because the exception is a connection reset.

Comment: Probably the server has closed the connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4300803/6371459. Are you using the same JDK? Have you configured the truststore? If the server requires two-ways authentication, have you configured the keystore?

Comment: yes I have connection, because it works at my local jetty.

Comment: Yes, I use the same JDK, I havent configured the truststore or the keystore. Because it worked on my jetty without any configuration so I thought it would work on tomcat without any major changes. The service I run against using TLSv1.2, could it have something with the error to do?

Comment: Right connection is there, but your Tomcat does not like requests from your client. So, it could be in SSL settings. You can run your client with -Djavax.net.debud=ssl and see in stdout log how it is going. At least there must be a certificate to trust on both sides, or two-way SSL can be required by your Tomcat server.

Comment: Okay I tried to debug ssl, this is the result:

http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 189
http-nio-8080-exec-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
http-nio-8080-exec-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-nio-8080-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called close()
http-nio-8080-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)

Comment: Can you use `openssl s_client` to try to connect to your server? I suspect the client is trying to use an `SSLv2Hello` protocol handshake to connect, but your server only supports a `TLS` handshake.