# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when connection time out >0

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am calling an api to send sms with a java apache common client, and it looks like setting a time out for more than 0 is returning a "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" error.

Here is a the code sample

```
// creating the http client
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

**Setting a connection time out of 10 sec (I receive a successful response 
          as soon as I remove this part of the code)**

```
client.getHttpConnectionManager().
getParams().setConnectionTimeout(10000);
```

Rest of the code

```
//creating the request method
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(smsUrl);

// setting its params  
method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[] { 
        new NameValuePair("username", user), 
        new NameValuePair("password", pass), 
        new NameValuePair("action", "sendsms"), 
        new NameValuePair("from", "Woosh"),
        new NameValuePair("to", toMobile), 
        new NameValuePair("text", textBody)
    });

//calling the method
method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
        new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Comment: @LarentB Its a different issue, mine is occurring because I am setting a connection time out. I get a successful response as soon as I don't provide any

Answer (score 0):

The issue was sorted out, it was an issue caused by the server of the api I was calling. Not sure what was it though