# AsyncTask - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask to fetch JSON data from a DB on my server. It works well normally but is failing sometimes with the below error. It seems like this happens when I keep the app idle but open for some time and then make a request.

doInBackground Method

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(url_get_initial_posts);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data_string_language = URLEncoder.encode("selected_language","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(arg_language,"UTF-8")
                    +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("app_time","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(arg_app_time),"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data_string_language);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((JSON_INITIAL_POST = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_INITIAL_POST + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This line in the error

```
W/System.err:     at com.indiparent.android.indiparent.PostTab$BackgroundJSONPosts.doInBackground(PostTab.java:343)
```

links to

```
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

Error

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:737)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:609)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:471)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
W/System.err:     at com.indiparent.android.indiparent.PostTab$BackgroundJSONPosts.doInBackground(PostTab.java:343)
W/System.err:     at com.indiparent.android.indiparent.PostTab$BackgroundJSONPosts.doInBackground(PostTab.java:308)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Extra Info - This is not the only Asynctask in the application. There are more in other activities and fragments. For example - if AsynckTask of Activity 2 throws this error then if I come back to Activity 1 then its AsyncTask also does not work.

Am I supposed to do something here or on the server side? Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Comment: `bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();`. I would not close the streams.

Comment: @greenapps So should I remove it from all Asynctasks? Also, how is it working normally and fails sometimes?