# Can I establish auto previous connection with same client after server down in socket

Tags: java, sockets, server

**I am doing one socket programming in java. If server socket is down for a while then start again after that the server can get auto connection with the same client which connect with previously. If possible can anyone help me how to handle the Exception**

```
SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:154)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
    at multiclients.MTServer$QueueClientThread.run(MTServer.java:29)
```

Comment: What is the exception you face

Comment: I attached above. Can u have a look?

Comment: have a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Comment: Sorry I can't able to get it.