# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset - when running with selenium grid

Tags: typescript, selenium, playwright

staring hub :
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-4.1.4.jar hub --allow-cors true --session-request-timeout 100000
staring node :
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps="" -jar selenium-server-4.1.4.jar node --publish-events tcp://:4442 --subscribe-events tcp://:4443 --port 5569 --grid-url http://:4444 --max-sessions 2 --override-max-sessions true

```
After a few minutes of running I get in the node :
    10:13:02.571 WARN [WebSocketHandler.handleException] - onError
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
10:13:02.572 WARN [ProxyNodeWebsockets$ForwardingListener.onError] - Error proxying websocket command
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
10:13:02.674 INFO [SessionSlot.stop] - Stopping session 008eb0c17a869ede98408f1a7994417b
10:13:02.705 WARN [WebSocketHandler.handleException] - onError
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
10:13:02.705 WARN [ProxyNodeWebsockets$ForwardingListener.onError] - Error proxying websocket command
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
10:13:02.799 INFO [SessionSlot.stop] - Stopping session 0dd823d09b8f94933007454c57cbab3b
Starting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904}) on port 60319
```

and part of the test failing on timeout,
the only way it fixed its by restarting the hub .

The tests run excellently without the GRID

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Comment: Unfortunately, no